# If else inside loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am breaking my head here, please help out.

I am crawling a website.

.MyElement containers contain either gif or jpg source urls that I am trying to fetch.

I am using Cheerio-based .each loop in my node.js app.

```
$('.MyElement').each(function(i, element){

    if ($(this).find($('.animation'))) {
        resourceLinks = $(this).find($('.animation')).attr('src'); //if there is an .animation class element, get the gif from it

    } else {
        resourceLinks = $(this).find($('img')).attr('src'); //in all other cases, just fetch regular jpg
    };

});
```

The first part (IF) executes fine, but the ELSE part is not executed at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$(this).find('.animation').length` is what you want to test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) always returns a jQuery object so it will always be truthy, if you want to check whether `this` has an element with class `animation` then check the length of the returned jQuery object

```
if ($(this).find('.animation').length) {
```

### }

You could also try(not tested)

```
$('.MyElement').each(function (i, element) {
    resourceLinks = $(this).find('.animation, img').attr('src');
});
```

Also if there is only 1 element with class `MyElement` then

```
resourceLinks = $('.MyElement').find('.animation, img').attr('src');
```

Comment: I suspect `$(this).find('.animation, img')` idea is based on "there is either `.animation` or `img`". So it will work incorrectly if there are both `.animation` and `img`.

Comment: Hey Arun, perfect, combination of .find and .length solved the problem! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

What seems to me you want to cache it in the var:

```
 resourceLinks = $('.MyElement').find('.animation').attr('src') || $('.MyElement').find('img').attr('src');
```

Instead of using jQuery objects try to find with class names:

```
    $('.MyElement').each(function(i, element) {
      if ($(this).find('.animation').length) {
        resourceLinks = $(this).find('.animation').attr('src'); 
      } else {
        resourceLinks = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
      }
    });
```

Comment: This didn't solve the problem, behavior was the same.